# chromium build error on windows7 32bit OS

Tags: windows-7, build, chromium

I am building chromium source code on windows7 32 bit machine. I am using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition. **I Build only** *chrome* **project**. I got the following error.

**328>..\build\Debug\obj\global_intermediate\chrome_version\chrome_exe_version.rc(5) : fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'verrsrc.h'.**

**328>chrome - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)**

**============== Rebuild All: 310 succeeded, 18 failed, 0 skipped =================**

**NOTE:**
Yesterday I started building chrome project and due to some reason i stopped build. Today i did Rebuild. Finally after 7 hours i got above error.

If anybody know about it please help me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verrsrc.h is available in Windows SDK software.

If you are getting this error means, you didn't properly configured Microsoft's Windows SDK or not installed it.

[Check whether you did this step or not](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-windows#TOC-Manually-registering-the-Platform-S)